# Unable to get fixed width fonts in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I start VSCode from Linux terminal and have X11 forwarding to display it back on my Windows PC.  I use XMing as the X Server.

The editor comes up fine but all fonts are variable width and have very poor quality.  The current setting clearly indicates fixed width fonts but it appears that it does not get used...

```
editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing my Terminal font within MobaXterm Configuration. I set the font to `Ubuntu Mono` instead of the default (which was `Mobafont`) and restarted MobaXTerm.

[This answer over here](https://superuser.com/questions/1134268/mobaxterm-powerline-font-issue) pointed me in the right direction.